# Dygraphs: Data format for Range Selector Graph

Tags: dygraphs

I need to know the acceptable data formats for Range Selector Graphs in Dygraphs. 
Here is my code which plots the data series

g1 = new Dygraph(
                  document.getElementById("graph"),
                  data_array,
                  {
                    customBars: true,
                    title: 'Daily Temperatures in New York vs. San Francisco',
                    ylabel: 'Temperature (F)',
                    legend: 'always',
                    labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
                    showRangeSelector: true
                  }
              );

data_array = [[Date(2013-1-1) , 13],[Date(2013-1-2) , 1],[Date(2013-1-3) , 19],[Date(2013-1-4) , 9],[Date(2013-1-5) , 12]]

My data is not showing up in the graph.

Regards,
Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

The acceptable dygraphs data formats are described extensively [in the documentation](http://dygraphs.com/data.html).